# twisted python 2.7 integrate with confluent-kafka issue for a legacy system

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python, twisted.internet

First of all, yes it's a legacy system which is not yet completely ported to Python 3 yet.

I have this piece of code where there is a Twisted program which serves some HTTP request, for simplicity I'm not doing anything in the `GET` request but assume that there is some other complex stuff going on.

I'm using confluent-kafka==2.2.0 and Twisted==13.2.0

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, threads
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall
from confluent_kafka import Consumer, KafkaException
import json

# Function to handle Kafka consumer
def kafka_consumer():
    def fetch_data():
        def poll_kafka():
            msg = consumer.poll(0.1)  # Poll without a timeout
            if msg is None:
                return
            if msg.error():
                if msg.error().code() == KafkaException._PARTITION_EOF:
                    return
                else:
                    return
            else:
                # Process fetched data from Kafka
                commit_offset()  # Manually commit the offset

        def commit_offset():
            consumer.commit()  # Manually commit the offset

        # Execute Kafka polling in a separate thread
        d1 = threads.deferToThread(poll_kafka)

    def start_loop():
        lc = LoopingCall(fetch_data)
        lc.start(0.5)  # Fetch data every 0.5 seconds

    conf = {
        'bootstrap.servers': 'kafka_internal-1:29093',
        'group.id': 'your_consumer_group-2',  # Replace with your consumer group
        'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest',
        'enable.auto.commit': False  # Disable autocommit
    }

    consumer = Consumer(conf)
    consumer.subscribe(['jithin_test'])  # Replace with your Kafka topic

    start_loop()

# Web service handler
class WebService(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True

    def render_GET(self, request):
        # You can customize the response according to your needs
        response = {
            'message': 'Welcome to the Kafka consumer service!'
        }
        return json.dumps(response).encode('utf-8')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start the Kafka consumer in a separate thread
    reactor.callWhenRunning(kafka_consumer)

    # Run the Twisted web service
    root = WebService()
    site = server.Site(root)
    reactor.listenTCP(8180, site)  # Replace 8080 with your desired port
    reactor.run()
```

My initial goal is to poll every 0.5 seconds to Kafka and get the data and manipulate something with it.
I assume under heavy load (say we have multiple endpoints and maybe I'm doing a stress test by bombarding the endpoints with a lot of requests) the 0.5 seconds looping call won't be guaranteed.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

One option I was thinking of would use a dedicated Python thread for this and use a `Queue.queue` to pass data between the new Kafka thread and Reactor thread.
Would it be a safe option to use it this way?

I know Kafka uses poll mechanism not like you push to one end and after you subscribe to it by attaching a callback say `on_message` you will receive messages in that method/function.

Is there a better way to handle this?